# How do I connect Raspberry to power? What kind of cord would I need?

Tags: windows-iot

I am looking forward to buying Raspberry Pi 3 from Amazon. I want to test Windows 10 IoT. I am wondering what kind of cable do I need to connect it to power. How much energy does it need? Should it be something like a laptop cable with a transformer?
Thanks

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: Welcome @Powercut. All your needed information (and more) can be found on the [official Raspberry Pi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/), check the "Technical" or "Tech Specs" section of each product. It will tell you what power connector is needed and the amount of amps required. This community prefers if you did a quick google on the question, we love specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the Raspberry comes with a 5V / 3A power supply. The value of 5V is standard (can vary up to 5.20V) nothing more. The current can be up to 2.5A.  I use a usb cable anyway.

Comment: 5.25V. Consider the voltage drop on the wire. Even 5.8 can be tolerated by the Pi (but perhaps not USB peripherals).

Comment: Yes. I noticed that when I connect a 5inch touchscreen display plus a wireless mouse, Raspberry shows a "power out" signal. After much research, I found a video in Portuguese that the guy shows that there is voltage drop in Raspberry of about 0.20V. So I use a power supply that gives 5.25V to 5.3. The "lightning" signal never appeared again.

Answer (score 2):

Officially the rating is 5V-3A. But Raspberry Pi works very well with a 5V-2.5A adapter. If you have a 2.5 ampere mobile charger you can use that too. But never use a fast-charger.
If you want to use all the ports in Pi then you should use a 5V-3A charger.
I have a guess that you want to use a voltage regulator as well. It will work, but you have to be extremely careful about that.